# Why am I getting errors in my stack data structure?

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I decided to make a stack using C. I just wrote the code for a *push* function and now I'm getting errors (it says something is wrong with my `maxsize`).

I f you ask me everything seems just right, and I don't have any idea on what would the error might be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define maxsize 100;

int top=-1, item;
int s[maxsize];

void push()
{
    if (top == maxsize-1)
    {
        printf("Stack overflow\n");
        return;
    }

    top = top + 1;
    s[top] = item;
}
```

The error that I am getting is:-

```
stack.c:3:20: error: expected ']' before ';' token
#define maxsize 100;
               ^
stack.c:5:7: note: in expansion of macro 'maxsize'
int s[maxsize];
  ^~~~~~~
stack.c: In function 'push':
stack.c:3:20: error: expected ')' before ';' token
#define maxsize 100;
               ^
stack.c:9:16: note: in expansion of macro 'maxsize'
if (top == maxsize-1)
           ^~~~~~~
stack.c:9:8: note: to match this '('
if (top == maxsize-1)
   ^
stack.c:16:5: error: 's' undeclared (first use in this function)
s[top]=item;
^
stack.c:16:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once
for each function it appears in
```

Comment: Can you please post the error output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define` directives do not end with a `;`. Change to `#define maxsize 100`

Comment: That is not generally true. Perhaps qualify your statement? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68515915/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define maxsize 100

int top=-1,item;
int s[maxsize];

void push()
{
    if (top == maxsize-1)
    {
        printf("Stack overflow\n");
        return;
    }

    top = top + 1;
    s[top] = item;
}
```

Here you used `;` after the `#define` statement which caused the problem.

Comment: Perhaps explain ***why*** it caused the problem? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68516439/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Okay sure thanks for suggesting me. I will do it.